# variable Postgres

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a little problem...
I have this error :
"SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « 'aliases' »↵LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 'aliases'↵ …"

But I really doesn't understand why ^^'
Here is my code :

```
function getAllByTable($nomTable){

    $bdd2 = DB::connection('kal');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $nomTable";

    return $bdd2 -> select($sql);
}
```

I have tried putting '$nomTable' in the From but it's not working... The name aliases is also right...

Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: Tip: The conventional syntax is `$x->y()` with no spacing.

Comment: Show us the final `$sql` string.

Comment: Thank you ^^ but it still not working...

Comment: return response()->json(getAllByTable(aliases));
I have tried putting quote around the aliases but not working : " ' ' "

Comment: Where and how do you create $nomTable ? That variable has the wrong data, and that ends up in your SQL.

Comment: I have a tab[] where I have all the tables names and I'm calling (getAllByTable($tab->tablename)) like that and for the test I have tried calling directly 
`return response()->json(getAllByTable(aliases));` I have tried 'aliases' with simple quote but it still not working....
It's weird because I have a similar function that is working `$sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$nomTable';";` No problem with the $nomTable

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes around the table name.  **'**aliases**'**

Comment: It's shouldn't be there ? I didn't add any quote ^^'

Comment: It seems that php add single quotes. you should try to do this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$nomTable;`
Or $nomTable contains 'aliases' with single quotes

Comment: It's still not working.... I don't understand why TT

Comment: What's the value of $sql in debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `SQL`, but in `PHP`, so it should work:

**`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$nomTable." ";`**

**or**

**`$sql = "SELECT * FROM '".$nomTable."' ";`**

Comment: It's weird it's not working too.... 
I have this error for both of them: "Use of undefined constant aliases - assumed 'aliases' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"